# TSQL INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm building an IT support ticketing portal for a multi-site company.
I cant get my head around JOIN, INNER JOIN, ON , etc.

I have 3 tables:

- Firstly `Support_Ticket` containing `Site_ID`, which I already have from a previous query.

So I have the `Site_ID`, and need to get the name (string) of the engineer that is responsible for support on that site. Lets say `Hull` is `Site_ID:1`.

The other 2 tables :

- `Site_Details`: containing (among others) `Site_ID` and `Site_Default_Engineer_ID`.
- `Engineers`: containing (among others) [`Engineer_ID`] and `Engineer_Display_Name`.

What I want to achieve is (pseudo-code!):

```
return [Engineers].[Engineer_Display_Name]  
where
    [Engineers].[Engineer_ID] = [Site_Details].[Site_Default_Engineer_ID]
    (but first) return [Site_Details].[Site_Default_Engineer_ID] where
    [Site_Details].[Site_ID] = [Support_Ticket].[Site_ID]
```

if that makes sense?!

Comment: what have you tried so far? It would be useful to see something you've tried even if it failed.

Comment: I'm currently running 2 separate queries (on a 'that'll work till i refine it' basis)


            sql = "SELECT [Site_Default_Engineer_ID] from [Site_Details] WHERE [Site_ID] = " + siteNo.ToString()
           (some code)
                    engineerID = dbread2.GetValue(0).ToString()
           (some code)


            sql = "SELECT [Engineer_Display_Name] from [Engineers] WHERE [Engineer_ID] = " + engineerID
            (some code)
                    engineerName = dbread1.GetValue(0).ToString()
            (some code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This query should work:

```
SELECT support_ticket.something, engineers.engineer_display_name
FROM support_ticket
JOIN site_details ON ( site_details.site_id = support_ticket.site_id )
JOIN engineers ON ( engineers.engineer_id = site_details.site_default_engineer_id )
```

It will present all tickets and their default engineer. Add a `WHERE`-clause to filter the ticket(s) you want to display.

BTW: There is no difference between `JOIN` and `INNER JOIN`.